# Getting some issue when executing query of time

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I'm fetching time from data database and executing some condition but it's not work properly. I can't understand what's is problem in this code. My code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
  $currentDay=date("l");

  $status="SELECT * FROM nesbaty_working_time WHERE provider_id='".$r."' AND day='".$currentDay."'";

  $qry_res2 = mysqli_query($con, $status);
     $array1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res2);
     $opening_time = $array1['opening_time'];      
     $closing_time = $array1['closing_time'];     
     $currentTime=date("h:i A");

   if (($opening_time < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $closing_time)) 
   {             

        $response['status'] = "Open";
   }
  else
  {
        $response['status'] = "Close";
  }
```

what is problem i can't understand. It always execute else part. My database look like this [image]

Comment: Although it isn't 100% definite from your example, you're code might be wide open to [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)!

Comment: BTW, this type of time format would be in text. So your `if` condition is not going to compare them in any way.

Comment: Yes it compares but it compares as string so 11:00 AM is greater than 07:00 PM. It won't work as intented

Comment: so! how can i manage AM PM issue?

Comment: By choosing a proper storage format for this to begin with. am/pm is _localized formatting_, this has no place being in your database to begin with. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare AM/PM times as strings. If the current time is `11:00 AM`, it is not less than `05:00 PM`, because `1` is greater than `0`. And if it's `01:00 PM`, it's not greater than `10:00 AM`, because `0` is less than `1`.

You need to convert the times to 24-hour time to be able to compare them properly. Or just convert them to timestamps.

```
$currentTime = time();
$openingTime = date_create_from_format('H : i A', $array1['opening_time']);
$closingTime = date_create_from_format('H : i A', $array1['closing_time']);

if ($openingTime <= $currentTime && $currentTime <= $closingTime) {
    $response['status'] = "open";
} else {
    $response['status'] = "closed";
}
```

Comment: Duh, of course it's `strtotime`. I always get that confused.

Comment: yeah !! i have already made that changes but still it not working!

Comment: In your second row, the opening time is after the closing time. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. You can use `echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $variable);` to see if it's parsing the time correctly.

Comment: That's what I meant, in the screen shot you show an opening time `08:00 PM` and closing time `07:00 PM`. It opens an hour after it closes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172229/discussion-between-pravin-suthar-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

You should try this function to make your data in proper format

```
$openingTime = date_create_from_format('H : i A', $your_variable);
$closingTime = date_create_from_format('H : i A', $your_variable);
```